# Iterating linked list issue

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Let's say I have the following structs:

```
// structures
typedef struct student {
    char *name;
    int  id;
    struct clist *courses;
} student;

typedef struct course {
    char *title;
    int  number;
    struct slist *students;
} course;

typedef struct slist {
    student      *info;
    struct slist *next;
} slist;

typedef struct clist {
    course       *info;
    struct clist *next;
} clist;
```

Let's assume that `clist` and `slist` have content inside.
Now for my question:
I am having a problem iterating the `clist` and `slist` structs (linked lists).
I made the next function for adding course to student courses:

```
void reg_student(slist *students,clist *courses,int id,int number){
  clist* Cpointer=courses;
  slist* Spointer=student;

  //finding course location
  for(;Cpointer->info->number!=number;Cpointer=Cpointer->next);

  //find student location
  for(;Spointer->info->id != id;Spointer=Spointer->next);

  //adding course to student courses list
  Spointer->info->courses=Cpointer;
  Spointer->info->courses->next->NULL;
  return;
}
```

When it start searching for the location of the course, it removes all the courses before him.
for example lets say I am looking for course number '555' and I have 3 courses in the list of courses - ('111,'222,'333') , once the function finish only  '333' is in the list.

How can I iterate the struct without removing things inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from Austin's answer, first, it is hard to tell where all your problems may originate without a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

However, it appears your use of 4-lists is causing your great difficulty in keeping your pointers straight (as Austin noted in his answers you will need separate `students` lists for each `course` and separate `courses` list for each `student`). The difficulty I see is a wildly near recursive number of lists will be required each time you iterate over either a student or a course. For example when you iterate over `slist` it includes a `clist course *info` which in turn will include `slist` and `student *info` again, e.g.

```
slist students
    student info
        name
        id
        clist course info
            { multiple inclusions of independent slist follows }
            title
            slist next
        clist next
    slist next
```

The same applies to `clist`,

```
clist courses
    course info
        title
        number
        slist students
            { multiple inclusions of independent clist follows }
            ...
    clist next
```

Now I'm not saying you cannot populate a big enough block of memory and populate each pointer address with the proper pointer address and pull this off, but buy stock in an Aspirin company...

Why not take some of the headache out of it and redo you layout with 2 structs, something like:

```
typedef struct student {
    char *name;
    int  id;
    struct course *courses;
} student;
```

and

```
typedef struct course {
    char *title;
    int  number;
    struct student *students;
    struct course *next;
} course;
```

Now you will still have the same issue of having to build each `student` node with a separate `course` list, and you will still have to build each `course` node with a separate `student` list, but you will greatly reduce the number of pointers your are required to manage by doing so.

If you post an MCVE, I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about *ownership.*

When you are passed `students` and `courses,` those are lists. What kind of lists are they?

I suspect, since you're writing this function and asking this question, that they're lists of "all students" and "all courses."

So, if you were to change a pointer in one of the "all courses" entries, you would be affecting *all the courses.*

That's probably not what you want.

So, who owns what? There's an "info" structure that contains details about the course, or the student. And there's a "list" structure that ties one item in a list to the next item in the list.

The courses and student info structures are probably universal. Maybe not quite immutable, but certainly they can be shared. I'll even suggest that it's a *feature* to share them - if someone changes the course info for `(course){ "CS-204: Introduction to C programming", 77204 }` it's probably a good thing if that change is reflected everywhere.

So you have some sort of "universal" ownership of the info structures. But the individual *lists* can be a different story. It's okay for there to be an "all courses" list, as well as a "courses being taken by this student" list, and for those lists to be different.

Different lists will mean different next pointers. So you'll need to create a separate list record for the student. Something like this:

```
begin register_student(all_students, all_courses, student_id, course_num)

    student = find_student_id(all_students, student_id)
    if !student
        fail or report error

    course = find_course_num(all_courses, course_num)
    if !course
        fail or report error

    new_list_entry = make_new_course_list_entry(course)

    insert_new_course(student, new_list_entry)
```